# How to handle data types in conversion from PHP Mysql API to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am in the process of converting our site from the PHP Mysql API to PDO, and have run into an issue with data types.

Previously, we escaped all of our variables as if they were strings. for example,

```
SET varname = '$varvalue'
```

Now, with PDO, of course, I do

```
SET varname = :varvalue
```

then we have a class that handles binding of the value of $varvalue, setting the data type based on the type of the variable.

The problem for us comes when varname is supposed to be a string, and $varvalue is, for some reason, null.  previously, '$varvalue' would have just become '' when $varvalue is null.  Now, we are "properly" binding $varvalue as null, but the database field does not allow null.

I know that the most correct way to fix this would be to ensure that $varvalue comes into the function with the correct value, but we have a large legacy code base, and that would be really a lot of work to implement.  Another solution would be to explicitly cast every variable when we bind it to the correct type. We'd prefer a solution that avoids us having to explicitly cast every variable in our models, if possible.  Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since previously you did not mind having empty strings, why not just checking if var value is null or not?

```
$stmt->bindParam(':varvalue', (is_null($varvalue) ? '' $varvalue), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: A version of this may well work for us.  If we convert all null values to empty strings, then create a new function specifically for the rare case where we want to bind null values, we can avoid type casting for our strings.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be an answer you were waiting for, but it should be mentioned: use exceptions.

You can configure PDO to throw exceptions of type `PDOException` instead of relying on return values:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can catch these exceptions and log them, email them, etc. so that you can identify exactly what piece of code was passing in the wrong values and fix it.

This is a somewhat painful operation; we've had to endure this ourselves when we started to report all uncaught exceptions on our website and our inboxes were cluttered with errors. It lasted a few days, but we managed to weed out all the really bad code :)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be using an abstraction for your application rather than using PDO directly. In your abstraction layer you can perform any type conversions you want to perform.

If this is absolutely not an option and you *must* use PDO directly, then you can try subclassing and delegation to produce PDO-workalike objects that perform the typecasting you want. However, if there is any column that *does* expect null, you are going to greatly complicate your abstraction layer. You may need to do introspection on the database or some other trickery. You will probably not be able to preserve the PDO API exactly.

### `PDOStatement` Delegation

This is pretty straightforward for `bindValue`. However, `bindParam` uses references and we can't typecast those without rewriting them, so we need a workaround that converts these to `bindValue` calls when `execute` is called.

First we subclass `PDO` so it returns our new wrapped `PDOStatement`.

```php
class PDO_nullcast extends PDO {
    public function prepare($statement, $driver_options=array()) {
        $prepared = parent::prepare($statement, $driver_options);
        $delegated_prepared = new PDOStatement_nullcast($prepared);
        return $delegated_prepared;
    }
}
```

Then we create a delegate `PDOStatement_nullcast` which has your null-casting semantics. Our first try will only override `bindValue`.

```php
class PDOStatement_nullcast {
    protected $pstmt;
    protected $bindparams; // this is for later
    function __construct(PDOStatement $pstmt) {
        $this->pstmt = $pstmt;
        $this->bindparams = array();
    }
    function __get($k) {
        return $this->pstmt->{$k};
    }
    function __set($k, $v) {
        $this->pstmt->{$k} = $v;
    }
    function __call($k, $a) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->pstmt, $k), $a);
    }
    function bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type=PDO::PARAM_STR) {
        $newvalue = $this->castValue($value, $data_type);
        return $this->pstmt->bindValue($parameter, $newvalue, $data_type);
    }
    static public function castValue($val, $typehint) {
        $newval = $val;
        if ($val===NULL) {
            if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_STR) {
                $newval = '';
            } else if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_INT) {
                $newval = 0;
            } else if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_BOOL) {
                $newval = false;
            }
        } else {
            if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_STR) {
                $newval = (string) $val;
            } else if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_INT) {
                $newval = (int) $val;
            } else if ($typehint===PDO::PARAM_BOOL) {
                $newval = (bool) $val;
            }
        }
        return $newval;
    }
}
```

Here is some demonstration code. We will be using the following table as an example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `typetest` (
  `intcol` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `strcol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `intnullcol` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intstrcol` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Now the PHP code. Assuming you have a `PDO_nullcast` object assigned to `$db`:

```php
$sql = 'INSERT INTO typetest (`intcol`, `strcol`, `intnullcol`, `intstrcol`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
$insert = $db->prepare($sql);
$insert->bindValue(1, null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(2, null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindValue(3, null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindValue(4, null, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->execute();
$insert->closeCursor();

$select = $d->prepare('SELECT * FROM typetest');
$select->execute();
$res = $select->fetchAll();
$select->closeCursor();

var_dump($res);
```

You can change the `castValue` function to the semantics you want.

However, this will not handle the `bindParam` case. Here we need to keep a reference around internally until `execute` is called on our wrapper, then convert these to `bindValue` calls. We can't handle all uses of `bindParam` this way, though! There's no workaround for INOUT parameters because we can't preserve the reference through typecasting.

We can intercept `bindParam` and `execute` calls like so to get what we want (add the following methods to the `PDOStatement_nullcast` class above):

```php
function bindParam($parameter, &$variable, $data_type=PDO::PARAM_STR, $length=null, $driver_options=null) {
    if (isset($length) || isset($driver_options) || ($data_type & PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT)) {
        // in either of these cases, we cannot wrap!
        return $this->pstmt->bindParam($parameter, $variable, $data_type, $length, $driver_options);
    }
    // note we preserve a reference to the variable
    $this->bindparams[] = array($parameter, &$variable, $data_type);
    return true; // this is a bit of a lie--we can't know if we would have an error until later.
}
function execute($input_parameters=null) {
    if ($input_parameters!==null) {
        return $this->pstmt->execute($input_parameters);
    }
    // for-loop is to preserve references more clearly
    // foreach is trickier
    for ($i=0; $i < count($this->bindparams); $i++) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this,'bindValue'), $this->bindparams[$i]);
    }
    return $this->pstmt->execute();
}
```

And here is some test code using `bindParam`:

```php
$var = null;
$insert->bindParam(1, $var, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindParam(2, $var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insert->bindParam(3, $var, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$insert->bindParam(4, $var, PDO::PARAM_STR);
error_log($var);
$insert->execute();
$var = 1;
$insert->execute();
$var = 2;
$insert->execute();
```